# VS 2017 Build Errors - Duplicate Attributes in AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: visual-studio-2017, build-error

I am developing a web application which started life by running `dotnet new angular` ([Clear blog explanation of usage](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/04/20/dotnet-new-angular-single-page-application-setup-and-how-the-template-works/)).

To extend the functionality of the default code I started developing a Web API. I added 3 new .Net Core Library Projects named `Shared`, `Scheduling` and `Scheduling_Tests`.

Some Domain Model classes were defined in `Scheduling`, some base classes were defined in `Shared` and finally some NUnit tests were defined in `ShedulingTests`.

When I build the Solution, 2 new folders appear in my Web Application project: `Shared` and `Scheduling`. I also get build errors like the following:

```
Error   CS0579  Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute'
```

I'm not sure where to go with this one, any advise would be very welcome.

Answer (score 15):

This happens because the new .NET tools automatically create the attributes and add them to the assembly, so they now appear twice in the build.

There are two ways to fix it:

1. Delete AssemblyInfo.cs
2. Keep AssemblyInfo.cs, but add tags to your CSProj file to suppress the attributes in AssemblyInfo.

For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>  
  <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>    
</PropertyGroup>
```

(Thanks to https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/dealing-with-duplicate-attribute-errors-in-net-core/)

Comment: Add <GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute> for net7.0 if using the second method

Answer (score 2):

Have you check if there is any **AssembleyInfo.cs** file available in your project? If yes, then try to delete it and rebuild your project.

Comment: I have a project that does not have an AssemblyInfo.cs file. It just keeps getting created on build and then causing the build to fail. The project I am working on started out as a .net core project. not sure what keeps causing this problem.

Comment: Manually deleting from obj, then clean and rebuild fixed the issue for me.